# Remove Date & Class Name from Console Output using java.util.logging

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I'm working with java.util.logging and I was wondering how I can remove the date and class name from the console output. I read some similar posts but none seemed to solve the problem. In order to fix the issue, I tried creating a CustomFormatter and overriding some of the methods, but that didn't work either. Here's what my code looks like:

```
public class CustomFormatter extends Formatter {
    public CustomFormatter() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record){
          return "testing";
    }
    @Override
    public String formatMessage(LogRecord record) {
        return "testing";
    }

}
public void logStuff() {
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
    logger.info("log stuff");
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
testingAug 13, 2015 9:37:12 PM className     <init>
INFO: log stuff
```

I want to get:

```
INFO: log stuff
```

Comment: That is a different question i guess. Here he wants a different output.

Comment: Check this:
https://prab2112.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/implement-a-custom-logger-using-java-util-logging/

Comment: @nginx No, same question, same answer, he is getting two sets of output, needs to remove the defualt console handler.

Comment: Actually what he wants is while logging to Console "testingAug 13, 2015 9:37:12 PM className     <init>" this line shouldn't get printed.

Comment: Don't install addtional ConsoleHandlers and set the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) property of the [SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html).  Remove the quotes from the pattern if you are going to set it up via a properties file.  The pattern you are looking for is something like java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="4$s: %5$s%6$s%n"

Comment: @jmehrens I tested this in Eclipse; the problem is that the parent console handler is getting added. Your proposed dupe doesn't even address that problem.